# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ (\log x)^2}{x^n}, n>0$

Tags: limits

It’s a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form

Here is what I tried
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ (\log (1+(x-1))^2}{(x-1)^n}$$

I tried reducing it to the standard from, but the $n$ i hindering the process. How do I proceed?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to use l'hospital?

Comment: If you know the limit of $\log(y)/y$ as $y\to +\infty$, put $x=y^{2/n}$.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I am fine either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n>0;

Hospital:

1)$ \dfrac{2\log x}{x(nx^{n-1})}= \dfrac{2\log x}{nx^n};$

And again:

2)$\dfrac {2}{x(n^2x^{n-1})}= \dfrac{2}{n^2x^n};$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Let $\log x=y, x=e^y$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(\ln x)^2}{x^n}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\dfrac{y^2}{e^{ny}}$$

Now $e^{ny}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{(ny)^r}{r!}$

Now divide the numerator & the denominator by $y^2$

Comment: Or use ratio test for sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Since, $\log x < x$ for all $x>0$,
$$
\log x = \frac{4}{n}\log(x^{n/4})  < \frac{4}{n}x^{n/4} 
$$
and therefore,
$$
0<\frac{{(\log x)^2 }}{{x^n }} < \frac{{16}}{{n^2 }}\frac{1}{{x^{n/2} }} \to 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to rewrite this as
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{\log(x)}{x^{n/2}}\right)^2$$
and use theorems on limit comparisons to show that the function in the brackets tend to $0$.